# How to replace columnA with columnB in pandas dataframe by skipping the empty values in columnB

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have 2 columns A and B ,

```
Column A  Column B

1          
2         4
3
```

I want to replace ColumnA with ColumnB but it should only replace non-empty values .

Expected output

```
coulmnA
1
4
3
```

and it should not be

```
CoulmnA

4
```

please let me know how can I achieve this , I tries to use df.replace but it copies all the values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using the apply function and lambda function combined to make it vectorized and this very fast.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'coulmnA': ['sad', 'ddsf', 'abc' ], 'coulmnB': ['', 'sdf', '']})
df
```

Out[1]:

```
  coulmnA  coulmnB
0   sad    ddsf
1   ddsf   None
2   abc    None
```

```
df.coulmnB = df.apply(lambda x: x.coulmnB if not x.coulmnB == '' else x.coulmnA, axis=1)
df
```

Out[2]:

```
   coulmnA  coulmnB
0   sad     ddsf
1   sdf     sdf
2   sdfa    sdfa
```

Comment: what is the  type of other values in your columnA?

Comment: You shouldn't use the name of the dataframe as the variable `x` in my code. You are using the variable name `Final_Extract` also in places of the `x` from my code. Use some other variable name and it will solve your issue.

Comment: The dataframe name should not be replaced. In your case, the code should look like `Final_Extract['Isubln'] = Final_Extract.apply (lambda x: x['Isubln'] if not np.isnan(x['Isubln']) else x['Isublnlpl'], axis=1) `

Comment: The `x` here when `axis=1` means that you are passing one line as a `pd.Series` and then extract the value form the `pd.Series` with `x['ColumnName']`.

Comment: The reason why you get the error was that it was string type and `np.isnan` only works for native np types like float64, int32 etc. You can use `pd.isna` in place of `np.isnan` which takes into account all types. I have changed my answer, hope it works.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. This is the same structure for your dataframe right?

Comment: Actually changed the my dataframe structure in your above example . Column B has the None values not Column A

Comment: @manda1238, and you want to populate columnB right? in that case, `df.coulmnB = df.apply(lambda x: x.coulmnB if not x.coulmnB == '' else x.coulmnA, axis=1)`. You need to find out what is in that specific column value, so that you can compare it and assign values. I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: thanks , it worked , i have replaced the ' ' values with NaN and then applied the function it worked . I guess the issue was with the ' ' .

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df['Column_B'] != '','Column_A'] = df['Column_B']

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Column_A Column_B
0        1         
1        4        4
2        3
```

Comment: it copied the entire colimnB to ColumnA

Comment: This will not work as you need to use the `np.isnan` to check where it is `None` or not. @manda1238 refer to my answer.

Comment: @manda1238 Try to execute `df = df.fillna('')` before. It seems that empty values arent empty string (`''`), but NaNs.

Comment: Andrej : it still did not work , it copied all the values from B to A